# Combining SWIG with CMake and distutils

Tags: python, c++, swig, distutils

I have a SWIG project that I'm currently using for Python bindings. I am using CMake as a build system and am a bit confused how I should deal with SWIG.

In one section of the SWIG docs, it tells [how to use SWIG with CMake](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Introduction.html#Introduction_build_system). Up until now, this is what I have been doing and it works relatively well, but leads to some issues when I try to install the Python module. I looked back at the SWIG documentation and it [recommends using distutils for Python](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Python.html#Python_nn6). After a bit more looking, it seems that distutils can [directly handle SWIG interface files](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#extension-source-files).

These seem to be a bit conflicting as the distutils methods will handle building as well as installing, so using both CMake and distutils would have two systems building the bindings. My hope is that using distutils will make installation a bit easier than the hoops I have to jump through for installing to the current environment with CMake.

I have two primary questions with this:

1. Is there a preferred way of handling this? The documentation I have found seems to be conflicting.
2. Is using the distutils approach portable between languages? If I generate bindings for another language, will something similar to distutils be available for building and installing the binding for that language or will I possibly have to embed that logic into CMake? If the latter is the case, I would imagine that it would be a bit messy if some languages had bindings built by their package manager and other languages had to be in the CMake system. Should my language bindings be separate projects that have the C++ code and SWIG interface files as dependencies?

**Update:** Some time ago, I put together an [example on Github](https://github.com/danielunderwood/swig-example) that demonstrates using SWIG and CMake with Python.

Comment: 1. I used GNU autotools before and now I use CMake/CPackDeb for build, install and distribution. 2. Distutils is not "portable" between languages - it is a Python thing. I personally create bindings for a number of languages and have a generic interface file and language specific ones.

Comment: @JensMunk How well does that approach work for installing in something like a python virtualenv (or the equivalent in another language)? And I know that distutils is a python thing, but I was wondering if it may be a good approach to do project files for each language (distutils for python, maven for java, etc).

Comment: You can use `dpkg-deb -X your_package.deb virtual_location` to extract files into your virtual directory. Your package bundle contains python as well as binaries. To make things neat, I separate libraries and SWIG interfaces into separate binaries/packages. It is nice to have a package system, which allows you to reuse libraries across binaries.